# Need Insight - software developer needing webservice c# .net TO php mysql

Tags: c#, php, .net, mysql, web-services

I am a c++ developer and need insight with current project...

I have a C# .net application that I want to securely connect to a mysql database

I have a sql database created and have created a "webservice" using php that I supposedly can connect to and through that it will access my sql database

but Need some insight into how to talk to this php code

Also would like to hear thoughts on this metholidgy ... is this best practices for doing this? (most secure, fastest, what about hundreds (thousands?) of users accessing a database will this hold up?)

- My end result is to have this run on mobile platforms (android, ios) using Unity3D

I am trying to get the basic running using .net 3.5 c# so I understand it before I have to port it to mobile platform and the .net subset with unity

If someone would help me outside of the scope of answering these questions, I am always willing to pay to get this figured out

Answer (score 1):

A great choice that would be very easy to implement in PHP and C#, as a bridge, would be Web Services built using JSON as the interchange format.

This looks like a good basic introduction for a [JSON PHP Web Service](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json).

This is [another in C#](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/JSON-EnabledWCFServicesInASPNET35.aspx).

With a neutral interchange format you should be able to connect the two components with ease.

I prefer to use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) and it works really well with JSON object serialization. Though JSON serialization is built into the core framework now (since .NET 3.5).

Comment: Looks promising... going to look into your links more... Thanks!

is this sound like a solid approach? I am hoping for hundreds to thousands of hits a day - things liks logging in, checking account data etc

Comment: hmm... the c# example is for asp.net I need it for windows (android, ios) .net

Looking at the json.net - first glance documentation appers sparse so not sure if its for asp.net but gonna keep looking :) Thanks

Comment: @Mort346 it is a very solid approach depending on how you implement the services and the unique needs of your problem. Major sites that get a large amount of traffic use JSON as their interchange format for their web service APIs (namely Twitter, Facebook, and Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

+1 on using JSON, but only if actually needed.

You can treat 'talking' to the php code as any other webservice. Create your api on the server side (ie. what the scripts do, what params they need), then forget the implementation when writing the client code.

Think about security. If you'll be exchanging sensitive information, you may want to encrypt it. So... SSL.

Do you have user-specific data? You may want some kind authentication.

One easy solution, if you're an optimist, may be to use a private salt and hash your parameters to make sure requests are coming from code you have distributed. However, this won't stop one user to pose as another.

As for scaling, it all depends on just how many calls you do, how many concurrent users you have etc., only you can estimate this stuff. Getting a cloud account would be good. Set up everything on one box at first. As traffic increases, move the database on a new node, then add a webserver, a master-slave setup, a load balancer..etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a nice approach, just be very careful with authentication and security. Performance shouldn't be an issue as long as you optimize the access to the database (performant queries, caching on the client and the service if necessary).

As for the web service consuming in C#, you should use [service references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) for [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) web services, or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) for [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web services.

For more information on the subject, this kind of architectures are called [Service Oriented Architectures (SOA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_oriented_architecture).